# If an object is initialized in the service, do it is kept initialized when service is running in background

Tags: android, session, httpclient, androidhttpclient

I am creating a Login Logout android application, in this application I am interacting with server and when I login the DefaultHttpClient object is initialized and with the login of the user, the DefaultHttpClient is associated with that user and session is running on the server until the app is running in front its initialized. But as soon as I destroy the app, the new DefaultHttpClient object is initialized and therefore it is not associated with previous login  but the session on the server is still running because I have not logged out yet.
Please Help how to keep my login session running even if the app is destroyed.

Comment: I don't think keeping a connection to the server a good idea of a logged in app. I think you should consider using SharedPreferences to store credentials and do REST requests. But that's my opionion.

Comment: Yeah I have done that using SharedPreferences but still if session is stopped..

Comment: If session is stopped, you should catch the session expired error, retry the connection (maybe with credentials) and carry on. For that matter, I'd recommend using Oauth 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Really good point.

First we clear the use of session. Session is created at server which is valid for some specific time and it is set by the server.

So it is not that you leave the application your session is expired. Even you are in running application if session time is over it will not work.

To overcome this you need to implement auto log-in functionality in your app.

For example you calling a web-service and it return some response along with some code.

`response : {"code" : "200","message" : "log-in successfully"}`.

But when session is expired in any case the server should return some specific code instead 200.

```
response : {"code" : "704","message" : "session expire"}.
```

so you need to check your response code and if it is 704 for call log-in service again and start new session in background.

For that you need to store log-in service parameter in sharedpreference entered by the user.